# No such host is known in GetAddrInfo c# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to establish a server-client connection using sockets in c#. I am trying to establish the connection firstly from the same machine and in the second step from different computers. I came accross those posts for [server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) and [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx). My question is about client connection. I am trying to perform something like:

```
 private static void StartClient()
 {
    try
    {
     //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
     IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1:11000");
     IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
     IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

     // Create a TCP/IP socket.
     Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
     SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
     .......
   }
```

However I am getting the message:

> NO such host is known at System.NEt.Dns.GetAddrInfo

What is my issue here? Port 11000 is the same I am using from server. What should I add as hostEntry when I runnin locally and what when I am running client from other machine?

**EDIT:** When I change the line `Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1:11000");` to `Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");` or `Dns.GetHostEntry("serverIp");` I got the same message.

**EDIT2:** When I gave the ip of the machine everything worked properly. Is it possible to send a message from server to clinets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1:11000");`

You must not add the port when querying [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx):

> hostNameOrAddress
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The host name or IP address to resolve.

Comment: So you propose to do just the following Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");